# how can I see a math symbol before submit a question

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown-preview

I would like to know how to see a mathsymbol before I submit a post.
I would like to see the format before submit, because I want to send good posts to mathoverflow.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

As you type into the edit field, the formatted message should appear in the display field just below the edit field. The two fields should appear as below:

[image]

Comment: yes, I realized I can't see the edit field in my browser (firefox), very weird. It works perfectly in chrome

Comment: @user42912: the image above was made using Firefox 15.0.1 on a Mac. There used to be a button or link to hide the preview. I wonder if that flag got set in your session before the interface was removed. Perhaps logging out on Firefox and logging back in might fix the problem.

Comment: An OT question @robjohn: what is the system fixed width font your computer is set to use? It looks interesting.

Comment: @WillieWong: The preferences say Courier 13, but looking at the actual appearance, it is using Monaco 13.

Comment: Is there a way to see how comments are formatted before they are submitted?

Comment: @PerManne: Not that I know of.

Comment: @PerManne: I've used the following workaround when there was too much $\LaTeX$ complexity to just blindly submit a comment: Prepare the comment in the *Your Answer* field (hence with preview), then copy-paste the content to the comment field.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Great idea - simple and effective!