# Viewing LaTeX in a comment before posting

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, comment, markdown-preview

When I type up my answers in a text box similar to this, I am able to see what my answer will look like in a dotted rectangle right below this box, including all boldings, italics, and most especially LaTeX (which this text box does not do).

I'm sure someone has thought of this, so why would the same feature not be available for comments? 80% of the time, I make a mistake when I write LaTeX in my answers and comments, but at least in the answers I am able to catch my mistake before I post it.

Comment: Just to be sure that you are aware of this: you can edit your comments for 5 minutes after posting.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yup I know that, but it would still be a helpful feature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I asked the same question in a comment in [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6260/how-can-i-see-a-math-symbol-before-submit-a-question/6262#comment21879_6262), and Hagen von Eitzen suggested the simple workaround by using the answer field as a sketch pad, and then copying the text over to the comment field before posting.

Comment: Wow I feel silly now haha.

Comment: @mathguy: If you feel silly you should try walking. I hear the ministry of silly walks is opening up again!

Comment: I would accept this as answer, but I still want to know whether or not this feature could be added and if not, the reasoning for them not being able to add it.